# How can I use the dd command to clone a USB drive?

Tags: linux, bash, usb, clone, dd

I have created a USB with a Linux distro on it and would like to clone it to another USB drive. The drive with the distro on it is 256GB, the distro is on roughly 8GB partition of USB drive. The drive I'm trying to clone to is 32GB. I've been trying to use the `dd` command to clone the USB drive as shown below.

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4M status=progress count=15644672
```

I used `fdisk /dev/sdb` to get the sector size for the count attribute in the dd command. However, when I run the `dd` command, the progress is showing something like (17 GB, 16GiB copied). I assumed it would only clone the data portion of the 256GB drive onto the new USB drive.

I've also tried changing the block sector size to 512M but have similiar results.

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4M status=progress count=15644672
```

Any suggestions? Perhaps I'm not using the command correctly?

Edit 01/19/2021: So the data portion I wanted to copy over was copied successfully but dd still attempts to fill all of the space on the USB drive. I'm now wondering if it would be easier to just clone partition to a new partition instead.

Comment: you don't need count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count=` doesn't work with disk sectors – it works with the block size you specified in `bs=`. (The *default* block size in dd happens to be the same as one disk sector, but that's awfully inefficient.)

This means that with `bs=4M`, you're actually telling dd to copy 15644672 four-megabyte units, or 60 TB in total. To copy 8 gigabytes, you want `count=2048`.

Alternatively, `head -c 8G /dev/sdb > /dev/sdc` or `pv -Ss 8G /dev/sdb > /dev/sdc`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Changing count to 2048 seemed to resolve my issue. :D